# ANT truncate or regex

Tags: regex, ant

A novice question:

I have a string (each word separated by a single space):

ABC_01.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2017 ABC_02.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.6053 ABC_02.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.5643.

I need to select just ABC_01.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2017 using Ant.

The length of AAAA is not fixed but is always separated by a space from the next token. What is the easiest/best way in Ant to do it? Regex, truncate after *n* characters?

Comment: Beanshell approach: indexof the space (if the first char after the first space is fixed, use the space + the char), the substring(0, index).

Comment: @coolcfan , I am getting this only partially. Assume I am not much into coding (tool administrator actually), so would you be kind enough to elaborate/spoon feed please :)

Also, I'd prefer not to add another JAR - will that'd be required for beanshell ?

Comment: Could you please tell me the pattern of the string in detail?

Comment: Ok.. the string contains about 10 words e.g. Hello Darling Harry Has Come Home. Now I need to just select 'Hello'. All the words in the sentence will always be separated by a space. So Hello <space> Harry <space>...  The length of every word is fixed for now (36 characters), it might change in future to 37. So I am good with selecting the first 36 characters before the 1st space too. Hope this clarifies

Comment: OK... Beanshell needs additional JAR... It's bsf.jar. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies // And for the String -- you just want to get the first word like "Hello"?

Comment: Yes correct... just select first word before first space or first 'n' characters

Comment: Do you have ant-contrib installed?

Comment: @FailedDev .. yes, I have ant-contrib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ant-contrib's property regex :

```
<propertyregex property="truncated.string"
               input="${input.string}"
               regexp="(.*?)(?:\s.*|$)"
               select="\1"
/>
<echo message="My truncated string : ${truncated.string}"/>
```

Tested with ant 1.8.2 and ant-contrib.

**Edited after OP edited question.**

```
<target name="get-rel-baseline-name" depends="init-property">       
        <exec executable="cleartool" outputproperty="baselinelist">
            <arg value="lsstream"/>
            <arg value="-fmt"/>
            <arg value="&quot;"/>           
            <arg value="%[latest_bls]p"/>
            <arg value="&quot;"/>
            <arg value="stream:${SOURCE_STREAM}@\Res_VOB"/>                     
        </exec>         
        <propertyregex property="RLS_Baseline"
        input="${baselinelist}"                 
        regexp="(.*?)(?:\s.*|$)"
        select="\1"/>
        <echo message="The original list is ${baselinelist}"/>             
        <echo message="${line.separator}Truncated list is ${RLS_Baseline}"/>
```

gives me the output

`[echo] The original list is  A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2017 A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.6053.....`  so on for 10 baselines

```
[echo]
[echo] Truncated list is
```

Basically it does not select anything with \1.

If I give \0 it selects the whole string of course and the value of `RLS_Baseline` is same as `A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2017 A_12.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.6053.....`

Reedit after OP's request :

```
<propertyregex property="truncated.string"
               input="${input.string}"
               regexp="\s*(\b(\w|\.)+\b)"
               select="\1"
/>
<echo message="My truncated string : ${truncated.string}"/>
```

Comment: Ok, my mistake in being too generic about the string. The actual string is ABC_01.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2017   
 ABC_02.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.6053    ABC_02.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.5643  and I need to just select the string ABC_01.1_REL_B121001_10_25_2011.2017   So the dots are making this fail now.

Comment: @PulakAgrawal Please edit original question with input and wanted output. Be sure to account for all possible cases.

Comment: edited the original question though the regex you provided is the one which works for me after a little modification to include dots : regexp="\s*(\b(\w|\.)+\b)"  Though it works without the space \s too. So may i know why is that required ?

Comment: @PulakAgrawal Space is irrelevant since it will still match if there is no space. Of course the input you provide in your original question is WAY different that the one you had before. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again.. like I said i tried to be too generic and the question was not accurate. Anyways I have tested using the new regex and its not working . I also tested here http://regexlib.com/ to verify if there is a problem with my ANT script and still the same. Though ur earlier expression worked for me like i mentioned in my earlier post : (\b(\w|\.)+\b)

Comment: @PulakAgrawal Actually it does indeed work quite perfectly. I hope you replaced : ${input.string} with your actual string right?

Comment: @FailedDev.. lol .. of course I did. But if you still say it works, let me check again thoroughly. Will respond back soon.

Comment: @PulakAgrawal Just paste the code which does not work so we can sort it out.

Comment: updated the original question with the actual code which is not working with the new regex you provided.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the original regex you provided `regexp="\s*(\b(\w|\.)+\b)"`, so I can accept that as the correct answer. Thanks

Comment: @PulakAgrawal Done. Not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: thanks.. this is what i meant. I mean I wanted to accept the regex which worked for me as the answer so that for any future viewers, its useful. I have accepted your post as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what is working for me currently

```
regexp="\s*(\b(\w|\.)+\b)"
```